# Nginx returns wrong SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I have domains likes

- app.something.com
- app.uk.something.com

There is no issue when I access `https://app.uk.something.com/login` or other urls with path behind, it returns the site with correct certificate issued for `app.uk.something.com`.

However, when I access root, `https://app.uk.something.com/`, it redirects to `https://app.uk.something.com:8443` and gave an error

```
This server could not prove that it is app.uk.something.com;
its security certificate is from app.something.com.
This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

When I checked the cert, it uses the one assigned for `app.something.com`.

> I used acme.sh to issue certs.
>
> **What I have done**
>   actually, there are other sites like `app.us.something.com`, they works fine, so for nginx, I just copied their config, replace `server_name`, `cert`, `key` for new one. Everything is working accordingly except the root now.

Comment: Hello and welcome Kelvin. This question may be answered on stackoverflow. Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517238/nginx-using-wrong-ssl-certificate. Regards.

Comment: I suspect that, because of the non-default port number 8443 in the URL, that it is not nginx that is configured with an incorrect certificate, but a different application server that runs the app on port 8443. Check the TLS config of that app